# Converting a string to floats error

Tags: python, arrays, csv

So I am trying to run this piece of code:

```
reader = list(csv.reader(open('mynew.csv', 'rb'), delimiter='\t'))
print reader[1]
number = [float(s) for s in reader[1]]
```

inside reader[1] i have the following values:

```
'5/1/2013 21:39:00.230', '46.09', '24.76', '0.70', '0.53', '27.92',
```

I am trying to store each one of values into an array like so:

```
number[0] = 46.09
number[1] = 24.09
and so on.....
```

My question is: how would i skip the date and the number following it and just store legitimate floats. Or store the contents in an array that are separated by comma?

It throws an error when I try to run the code above:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 5/1/2013 21:39:00.230
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not `reader[1][2:]`? Also I would saving the whole thing in memory as a list if possible

Comment: Have you tried [float(s) for s in read[1][1:]]?

Comment: reader[1][2:] works thanks alot jamylak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just skip values which cannot be converted to float:

```
number = []
for s in reader[1]:
   try:
       number.append(float(s))
   except ValueError:
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the first value that's not a float, you can take it out doing:

```
reader = list(csv.reader(open('mynew.csv', 'rb'), delimiter='\t'))
print reader[1]
number = [float(s) for s in reader[1][1:]]
```

Comment: *"skip the date **and the number following it** "*

Comment: I was in doubt. His example contradicted this. Just replace the `1:` with `2:` then.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can search for / in the string and pass if exists, something like this

```
my_list_results = []
my_list = ['5/1/2013 21:39:00.230', '46.09', '24.76', '0.70', '0.53', '27.92']
for m in my_list:
    if '/' not in m: #if we don't find /
        my_list_results.append(m)
print my_list_results
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = []
for s in reader[1]:
   number.append(int(float(s)))
```

this will convert string into exact float